# Magento: how can I show all reviews of all products on a cms page

Tags: magento, review

I want to show all my reviews of all the products on a cms page. Does anybody know ho to do this? I'm using Magento 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

that all depends on what Module you're using to provide that extension to Magento's features. If you look in the folder of the module (let's say its Cmdcentral/Review)

```
app/code/community/Cmdcentral/Review/
```

This is where the module resides (it might be in local too)look in the `etc` for `config.xml` There will be a section that looks something like this:

```
<config>
 ...
   <global>
    ....
    <models>
      <review>
          <class>Cmdcentral_Review_Model</class>
      </review>
      <review_mysql4>
         <class>Cmdcentral_Review_Model_Mysql4</class>
         <entities>
              <reviews>table_in_database</reviews>
         </entities>
      </review_mysql4>
   </models>
  .....
 </global>
  ...
</config>
```

This will differ depending on what you've got. what's important is the name of the node inside `<entities></entities>` in my case it is `<reviews></reviews>`

You can then take a look at the `controllers` folder for `IndexController.php` create a new function that looks like this:

```
public function showallAction(){
   $this->loadLayout();
   $this->renderLayout();

}
```

Now you'll have to create a block for this, create a new block in `app/code/community/Cmdcentral/Review/Blocks` and call it `Showall.php`

Your block should look something like this:

```
<?php class Cmdcentral_Review_Block_Showall extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
   public function getAllReviews(){
       return Mage::getModel('review/reviews')->getCollection();
   }
}
```

`review` is module name and `reviews` is the entity we saw inside the `<entities></entities>` node in `config.xml`.

Next we're off to `app/design/frontend/` from here, the file we're looking for is most likely in `base/default` but may also be in another theme's folder. The file we're looking for will be `Modulename.xml` so in my case it will be `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/Review.xml`
Open your layout file, now simply add this inside the `<layout></layout>` node:

```
<review_index_showall>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="review/showall" name="showall" template="review/showall.phtml"/>
   </reference>
<review_index_showall>
```

This simply tells Magento that when we load our `review/index/showall` route and access our `showallAction()` function in our controller, to add our block inside content.

Now the block also has a `template="review/showall.phtml"` attribute. Go to `app/design/frontend/base/default` look for a `review` directory (or whatever the module is called). If it doesn't exist (which I doubt) create it! Inside this create `showall.phtml`. So now you should have it looking like `app/design/frontend/base/default/review/showall.phtml`

Open this file and now you create your page. ~Phew!

Just remember to use `$this->getAllReviews()` to get your review/reviews collection and then simply do something like this:

```
$reviews = $this->getAllReviews();
foreach($reviews as $review){
  echo $review->getData('column_name');
  #or
  echo $review->getColumnName();
  #does the same thing
}
```

I hope this helps and I didn't make any mistakes. Remember, at first Magento makes you cry, but when you get used to Magento, it's reduced to intermittent whimpers!